# Why it always show blank flash message when after typed keyword was okay in Recaptcha?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I always get this blank flash message popping up when after typed keyword was okay in Recaptcha. Why? and How can I fix this?

[image]

**routes**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
def create
    if verify_recaptcha
        super
        flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
        else
        build_resource
        clean_up_passwords(resource)
        flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
        flash[:alert] = "Typed keyword is not correct!"
        render :template => '/registrations/new' 
    end
end
```

**view for flash**

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flash.now[:alert]` or `:alert` option with `render` method for using flash message immediately.

Example:

```
render :template => '/registrations/new', :alert => "Typed keyword is not correct!"
```

Comment: Thanks:) As I said, it only pops up when typed keyword was correct. So the problem is not there:( inside of `super` is the problem part. or something is going on with the devise's default transcation?